# Force 2-dimensionality in vector

Tags: python, numpy

When I do `p = np.zeros((3,1))` I get a matrix in the shape (3, 1).

Sometimes when I am working with NumPy arrays that are nx1, however, I get that their shape is (3,).

How can I make these (3,) shaped arrays into (3,1)?

i.e. here is a minimum runnable program:

```
a = np.random.randn(3)
>>a.shape
(3,)
```

I want it to be (3,1).  I know I could just call with arguments 3,1 but this is just an example, sometimes I can't control the generative process but only manipulate the output.

Comment: The behavior you describe shouldn't actually be happening. If `p.shape == (3, 1)` and `A.shape == (5, 3)`, then `np.dot(A, p).shape` should be `(5, 1)`. Can you produce a [minimal runnable example that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's strange, I think scipy.optimization.minimize takes the (3,1) vector and makes it (3,).  Changing question.

Comment: Well, hopefully this version of the question reflects your situation more accurately, but it's also really vague. There could be all sorts of logic errors and misused library calls causing the problem, and we don't have much to go on. Again, a minimal example program that demonstrates the bug would go a long way toward making this problem solvable.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize` flattens the guess. Beware: it may not be possible to distinguish `(2, 2)`-shape arrays and `(4, 1)`-shape arrays without passing an additional shape argument to the objective function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the shape and add another axis if needed:

```
if len(a.shape) == 1:
    a = a[..., np.newaxis]

# or this, if you need more generality:
a = a.reshape(a.shape + (1,) * (desired_dimensions - len(a.shape)))
```

There's an [`np.atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html#numpy.atleast_2d) function, but it would produce a 1-by-3 array instead of 3-by-1.